# Why all radio inputs get selected at the same time?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, input, tailwind-css

I use Tailwind to create 3 radio inputs. When I click on one, all get the `ring-2`. I set a unique ID on each.

Why ?

[Tailwin Playground](https://play.tailwindcss.com/PBtNL5Zirz)

```
<div class="p-8">
  <form>
    <input class="peer sr-only" type="radio" value="yes" name="answer" id="answer_yes_1" />
    <label class="cursor-pointer rounded-lg border border-gray-300 px-8 py-2 text-neutral-500 focus:outline-none peer-checked:border-transparent peer-checked:shadow-lg peer-checked:ring-2 peer-checked:ring-black peer-checked:text-neutral-700" for="answer_yes_1">Classique</label>

    <input class="peer sr-only" type="radio" value="no" name="answer" id="answer_no_1" />
    <label class="cursor-pointer rounded-lg border border-gray-300 px-8 py-2 text-neutral-500 focus:outline-none peer-checked:border-transparent peer-checked:shadow-lg peer-checked:ring-2 peer-checked:ring-black peer-checked:text-neutral-700" for="answer_no_1">Immobilier professionnel</label>

    <input class="peer sr-only" type="radio" value="maybe" name="answer" id="answer_maybe_1" />
    <label class="cursor-pointer rounded-lg border border-gray-300 px-8 py-2 text-neutral-500 focus:outline-none peer-checked:border-transparent peer-checked:shadow-lg peer-checked:ring-2 peer-checked:ring-black peer-checked:text-neutral-700" for="answer_maybe_1">Programmes neufs</label>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [differentiate peers](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#differentiating-peers) by adding `/yes` `/no` to your **peers**

```html
<input
  class="peer/yes sr-only"
  type="radio"
  value="yes"
  name="answer"
  id="answer_yes_1"
/>
<label
  class="cursor-pointer rounded-lg border border-gray-300 px-8 py-2 text-neutral-500 focus:outline-none peer-checked/yes:border-transparent peer-checked/yes:shadow-lg peer-checked/yes:ring-2 peer-checked/yes:ring-black peer-checked/yes:text-neutral-700"
  for="answer_yes_1"
  >button 1</label
>
```

Same for the others

See here the [Tailwind Playground](https://play.tailwindcss.com/czWQhHayMd)

Comment: I didn't know this, thanks ! Could you provide a playground if possible ?